# access a dynamic created instance through a list ref Python

Tags: python-3.x, object

I have a bunch of team objects that I created and for each one on the creation I added the name of the instance to a list. How can I use this list to access each instance?

InstanceNames=['team1','team2','team3', etc...]

I want to know how to do this:

InstanceNames[0].playGame(InstanceNames[1])

(this should be like saying 'team1'.playGame('team2')

What I am really asking is how do I get the string returned from InstanceNames[0] on the left side so I can use each instance name dynamically in my code here is what I want to do:
InstanceNames[0].playGame(InstanceNames[1]
more specifically
x= 0 y=1 InstanceNames[x].playGame(InstanceNames[y])

playGame() in this case is a function in the Team class and takes the argument of the team to be played...

I would use this to eventually return the score of the game to each team, but I can figure that out once I learn how to dynamically place the team object name on the left side of the equation.

Any idea how to do this?(I am using Python 3.5.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want lists, you can add the instances themselves - not their names - to the list.

Your example above ill work out of the box if you do that.

Or, if yo will make actual use of the names, usea  dictionary instead of a list - the  you will be able to use the names as keys, and the instances as values:

```
teams = {}
teams["team1"] = Team(name="team1", ...)
...

teams["team1"].play_game(teams["team2"])
```

Comment: Thank you jsbueno for your quick reply. This kind of answers my question but not to the level I need. What I am really asking is how do I get the string returned from InstanceNames[0] on the left side so I can use each instance name dynamically in my code here is what I want to do

InstanceNames[0].playGame(InstanceNames[1])

more specifically x= 0 y=1

InstanceNames[x].playGame(InstanceNames[y])

This will allow my program to make the proper calls to the proper object

Comment: Sorry - this answers tells you _exactly_ howthis code snippet will work: if you want to acess a "playGame" method, on the left side of the `.` you need an instanc of your object, not  a string.

If you want to have the names, and them get to the objects, just use both parts of the answer: i.e.: keep a dictionary of your instances keyed by name, and a list with the names: `teams[InstanceNames[0]].playGame(...)`

Comment: You are right, I just misunderstood what you were saying the first time I saw it. I appreciate your help and I hope you have a great weekend!